# body.innerHTML and page source are different (YouTube)

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, console.log

Page source is newer than the document.body.innerHTML. Why? How?

I'm on an youtube page with playing video. I have Chrome's console and 'view page source' of that page.
Youtube has uniq signature of all videos. I'm doing these steps:

step 1:

> document.body.innerHTML.substr( document.body.innerHTML.indexOf('sig=') , 20)
>   "sig=8178A2C9DF5EF0DA"

Good. I see this string in the console and in the page source.

step 2:
I clicked one of the suggested videos on the right column and repeated code (there is no redirects):

> document.body.innerHTML.substr( document.body.innerHTML.indexOf('sig=') , 20)
>   "sig=8178A2C9DF5EF0DA"

Now I see that signature hasn't changed. But there is no such letters in the source code. How is it possible? Why innerHTML stays as it was?

Comment: You're seeing the HTML5 History API; they aren't updating all of the HTML.

Comment: But there must be "sig=8178A2C9DF5EF0DA" in the source code of new page, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because they are using the [HTML 5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

Comment: They have example. I run my test and got what I expected: document.body.innerHTML.substr( document.body.innerHTML.indexOf('photonav'), 100) - it gives me updated code, page source and innerHTML both have updated code. But on youtube page 'page source' is newer than body.innerHTML

Comment: What do you mean by *newer*? Is there somekind of a timestamp that makes you think that?

Comment: Yes. The signature that i mentioned in my question. Signature of old video stays in the body.innerHTML of new page. But 'page source' has no that string with signature.